# Konvajs: Transformer handlers scales with stage

Tags: konvajs

When stage's scale is 1 - Transformer's handles draw normal (image 1), but when stage is scaled - Transformer's handles visually scales with stage (image 2). Is it a method to prevent such a behaviour?

**Stage scale is 1**
[image: Stage scale is 1]

**Stage scale is 0.5**

[image: Stage scale is 0.5]

Comment: What konva version are you using? There were some related fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you updated scale of the parent node (stage) AFTER you created transformer try to update it:

`transformer.forceUpdate()`

Demo: http://jsbin.com/vigedihopo/edit?html,js,output

Also, you may add all shape into a `Konva.Group` and scale it instead of `Konva.Stage`. So `Konva.Transformer` will be placed inside not scaled container.

Comment: Updated to 2.1.8. Problem still present.
About stage scaling. I need to handle window.resize events. So, the whole stage should be scaled, not particular images. Maybe there is a proper approach to obtain this?

Comment: @PavelAksyonov can you make a demo? I made this demo: http://jsbin.com/rokexusalo/edit?html,js,output it works ok (anchors are not small).

Comment: Here it is: http://jsbin.com/decosataja/edit?html,js,output. Afrer scaling stage with stage.scale() anchors become smaller. Just move mouse to the circle.

Comment: @PavelAksyonov I see now, thanks for the demo. I update the answer.

Comment: Yes! It works with `transformer.forceUpdate()`. I think it would be nice if `stage.scale()` will do this.